# .htaccess redirect for partial path

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect partial path with `.htacess`. I need to redirect from

```
https://example.com/blog/archive/3312
```

To

```
http://blog.example.com/archive/3312
```

I tried with the following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?https://example.com/blog/(.*)$ /http://blog.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But it is not working. How can I solve this?

Comment: No. no. no. There are endless examples for this on the internet and there is an excellent documentation which helps. The protocol scheme is not part of the subject the rule matches against the pattern. _Read the documentation of the tools you use_. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `RewriteRule` you can only match request URI, for matching domain you need `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteEngine on

# comment out line below if you want to do this for both http:// and https://    
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?blog/(.*)$ http://blog.%1/$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But unfortunately it is not working for me.

Comment: Comment out both `RewriteCond` lines and retest after clearing browser cache.

Comment: Does `blog/` directory also have a .htaccess? Other than that there can be other 2 reasons for this not working. 1) This is not in site root .htaccess OR 2) There are other rules before this.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blog
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://blog.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for giving prompt answer. It is working but one problem is there it redirects with /blog/ part. means http://blog.example.com/blog/archive/3312.

Comment: This time it is not redirecting anymore.

Comment: What is the error? it is working here on live website please check where are you applying rule and comment other rule before testing.